# Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am doing the lazy loading approach. In that i got this problem

```
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".
```

with below code

```
 <li ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
   <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Problem can be importing "CommonModule" at your NgModule if you dont have any syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax of **`ngFor`** will be **`*ngFor`**, I think you have forgotten to place `*` before `ngFor`

```
   <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
       <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
   </li>
```